# Map reduce and hash partitioning

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-partitioning

While learning about MapReduce, I encountered [this question](https://github.com/abalone0204/Cloud-Computing-Concepts/blob/master/week1/07-mapreduce-paradigm-first-level.md):

> A given Mapreduce program has the Map phase generate 100 key-value pairs with 10 unique keys.
>
> How many Reduce tasks can this program have when at least one Reduce task will certainly be assigned no keys when a hash partitioner is used (select all answers that are correct)?
>
> - [ ] A. 3
> - [ ] B. 11
> - [ ] C. 50
> - [ ] D. 101
>
> The answers are B, C, D.
>
> Since the unique keys' number is 10. We must have at least 10 reduce task. And at least one reduce task has null key.

I am not able to understand how these answers where arrived at. Please help me in this.

Comment: I looked up the source of the question and edited it into your question, along with the explanation. Which part of explanation do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

Unique keys from the map output are assigned to only one reduce task. If there are 10 unique keys and there are 11, 50, or 101 reduce tasks then there will necessarily be some reduce tasks that have no keys.

Answer (score 1):

As there are 10 unique keys we need 10 reducers and since we want 1 reducer with no keys assigned, in total its 11 reducers.

If the number of reducers are more than or equal to 11, the job would run without exceptions. So *any number more than or equal to 11* would be an answer.

Comment: can't one reducer handle multiple key val pair?

Answer (score 1):

Hash partitioner in this context merely means reduce tasks will be consolidated by unique key. It is assumed that a reduce task is completed on only one server, therefore each of 10 tasks are atomic.

The modulo operator (or any reasonable partitioner) will assure that each of 3 servers/reducers will be active for the case of 10 tasks.

For the other options, if there are more "reducers" than tasks, all tasks will be assigned to one "reducer" (only one remainder), if we are to believe the partitioning function. This is ridiculous or at least confusing without additional context. Apparently, partitioning is only required when the number of tasks exceeds the number of reducers/servers.

Answer (score 0):

To get one reducer output as empty file, i.e., no key assigned to reducer, we need at least 11 reducers because hashpartitioner distributes based on hash function. The eligible reducers to receive data here are part-r-00000 to part-r-00009.

Reducer no = key hashcode % n ( no of reducers)

So possible remainders are 0 to n-1. Here we have 10 unique keys, i.e., 10 different remainders. We will have empty reducers files even if number of reducers less than unique number of keys. In the worst scenario also we will get one reducer file empty if the number of reducers is more than unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the question is asking at what number of reducers (picture a separate server for each reducer for example) you would be *overprovisioning* your reducers.  That is, what's more reducers than you need at a minimum here?

You have 100 key-value pairs with 10 unique keys.  So, you need at least 10 reducers because 100/10 = 10.  Fewer than that and you wouldn't have enough reducers—-your reducers would be underpovisioned.  With 10 reducers you have the bare minimum you need.  At more than 10 recuders, you would be overprovisioning--you would have more than you need at a minimum.  So, any number greater than 10 will give you at least one backup reducer.

You might of course wonder why someone would want to overprovision resources here. One reason might be fault tolerance.  If one of your reducers goes offline, then you would have one to spare.